# How can I upload SVG images using the media uploader?

Tags: uploads

I really love using SVG images as I can scale them as big or as small as I want. However, WordPress won't allow me to upload them using the media uploader. How can I change this?

[image: media uploader error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to filter the allowed upload file types and add the SVG filetype to the list:

```
function allow_svg_upload_mimes( $mimes ) {
    $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'allow_svg_upload_mimes' );
```

*Also on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/bungeshea/5279485)*

Comment: Not working (wp 5.0.8) - still receiving not allowed message